# LocalPushNotification sound and iPhone's volume buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, volume, uilocalnotification, audio

I implement UILocalNotification in my app which will play 16-seconds-length sound.
I notice that while the sound is being played,
if I press the side Volume buttons (on iPhone/ iPod) to increase or decrease the volume,
the sound is stopped immediately.

Do you know how to not stopped the Local Notification sound when user presses the side Volume buttons on iPhone/ iPod?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I like to do the same like this [i-iQ Timer](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/i-qi-singing-bowl-timer-free/id427428211?mt=8) app, when UILocalNotification sound is playing, if user adjust the side volume buttons, the sound keeps playing.

Answer (score 0):

No, the standard APIs give you no control over what happens when the volume buttons are pressed. The only sound-related thing about a `UILocalNotification` that you can control is to choose which sound plays.}

Comment: Hi yuji, thank you for quick response. Do you have any idea how the i-iQ Timer do so that when user adjusts the volume, the sound still keep playing?

Comment: It's not playing sound using local notifications: you can tell that because the sound will play even if you disable sound for that app in notification settings. Instead, it's keeping itself in the background by registering as an audio playback app (just playing a silent sound until the time is up, then playing the chime).

Comment: That's what I thought too, do you think if I do the same (playing a silent sound in the background) will make my app get rejected?

Comment: Anything I say would be speculation. But since it worked for them, maybe it'll work for you? I know that just playing a silent sound is usually frowned upon, but my guess is that it passed since they were doing it specifically so that they could play a sound, and only after a short period of time.